# SSRS issue with using dynamic fields in SP

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a SP like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ReportGateWay]
(
    @ISO  bigint= 0,
    @Gateway  bigint= 0
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
    SET @SQL= 'SELECT * FROM
                (
                    SELECT DISTINCT I.DBAName [ISOName], BG.GatewayName
                    FROM Iso I
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN BusinessGateway BG 
                    ON I.GatewayName = BG.MerchantBusinessGatewayId AND I.IsActive = 1 and BG.IsActive = 1
                    WHERE ('+CAST(@ISO AS varchar(10))+' = 0 OR I.IsoId = '+ CAST(@ISO AS varchar(10)) +')
                    AND  ('+CAST(@Gateway AS varchar(10))+' = 0 OR BG.MerchantBusinessGatewayId = '+ CAST(@Gateway AS varchar(10)) +')

                ) AS tb1
            PIVOT
            (
                Count(GatewayName) for GatewayName in ('+ SUBSTRING((SELECT ',[' + BG.GatewayName + ']' FROM BusinessGateway BG 
                WHERE @Gateway = 0 OR BG.MerchantBusinessGatewayId = @Gateway
                FOR XML PATH('')), 2, 200000 ) + ')
            ) AS pvt
            ORDER BY pvt.ISOName'

    EXECUTE (@SQL)

END
```

I need to invoke this in SSRS. The problem is that when on creating dataset for this, I get an error which read:

> You must have atleast one field for your dataset

What can be done in this case?

Comment: Her's the SQLFiddle demo Url - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/81e35/2

Comment: Have you looked into doing the Pivot in SSRS? That's the strength of the Matrix control in SSRS. I haven't dug into your query, but I'd be surprised if you couldn't simplify it and then use the Matris control to get the dynamic columns pretty quickly. [Also, more recent versions of SSRS will help a lot with this. I don't recall what the details for this were in SSRS 2005.]

Answer (score 1):

You have this error message because SSRS cannot infer your schema from the query.
You could declare manually your fields in *DataSet Properties* => *Fields*:

*Field Name*, *Field Source*

- ISOName, ISOName
- Gateway1, Gateway1
- Gateway2, Gateway2

**EDIT**

If you really want to have dynamic columns and can't define static column names, you could try a trick like [this](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/datadesign/dynamic-column-names-and-fields-in-ssrs/).
The idea is to create a function returning an Arraylist containing Column headers and values.

Comment: There can be more gateways and not just Gateway1 and Gateway2. Also, user can insert more gateways via a screen in the application in real time. Hence this option might not be feasable

Comment: @user3194125 - See my edit. Note that having dynamic columns in a report is not something recommended. But if you have no choice but to do it, then you can try the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not executing the Procedure by creating a dataset of **query type** "Stored Procedure"?

By doing this you will be able to see the fields getting returned from the SP in your dataset.

You can also pass the parameter values to the SP by creating the report parameters.

**Edit:**

How to pass parameter to SP in SSRS:

1. Say you have sp as below:

> ```
> create procedure [dbo].[TestProcpk] @value varchar(20)
> as
> select * from testProc where value = @value
> ```

2. You have to create parameters with same name as above i.e. **@value**.
3. I have below data in **testProc**:

   ID|Value

   1|xxx

   2|yyy

   3|zzz
4. If I run the report with parameter value of xxx, I will get 1|xxx only.

Also, You don't have to specify anything after selecting the SP from drop down.

How you are not able to pass param value to SP?

Comment: Created a query type stored procedure. Result comes correct. But unable to pass report parameters to this SP for some reason. Hence, filter of records is not working,

Comment: You can pass parameter to SP. See my Edit. What is the problem you are facing while passing?

Comment: SSRS can't parse result of dynamic-SQL query. So it can't get the result table from SP.